# How convolutional neural netwrk is working with RGB iamge input?

Tags: image-processing, neural-network, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, rgb

Currently I am working on my own CNN.I want to understand something.

If the input is RGB image. How I must merge this channels before fully connected network.Or must I merge this channels before first step and operate with this merged channel during all network?

I am taking from input 3 chanels.

Firts I am filtering R-channel than G-channel than B-channel with same filters.

After convolution and pooling I must convert it to 1D vector for fully connected layer.How I must convert this 3 channels together to one 1D vector? –

Answer (score 0):

Something you can always do is to convert your images to grayscale, but you can also handle your input in RGB. Just make sure that your layers correctly process your 3D data.

Comment: Yes I know that I can convert to grayscale but I want to process in rgb.I do not know how this 3 channels are merging in output.

Comment: Well, what is the purpose of your network, classification, segmentation? I suggest you add code or a more detailed description as it is not apparent what your issue is.

Answer (score 0):

It matters less HOW you marge them as much as it does to make sure you always encode the same way.
You have several options:
1) input array is all the red, followed by all the green, followed by blue
2) input is rgb of first pixel followed by rgb of next pixel ect.
3) etc.

It is just important to code the values the same way when you used the trained network.

Comment: Look. I am taking from input 3 chanels. Firts I am filtering R-channelthan G-channel than B-channel with same filters.After convolution and pooling I must convert it to 1D vector for fully connected layer.How I must convert this 3 channels to one 1D vector?